# How to remember other program instance variables in python

Tags: python, sockets, inter-process-communicat

This is related to socket programming

Well , Let's say I have a program `xyz.py`  which takes some command line arguments `abc`

so I run the program using the following command

```
python xyz.py abc
```

the program is running and not closed

Now I open a another terminal then run the **same** program using and with different command line arguments `hhh` , the command would be

```
python xyz.py hhh
```

Even this Window( program is not closed )

Now the question is now if run the **Same** program for the third time using another terminal

How do i make the the third instance of the program to know the values of `abc` and `hhh` respectively ?

and also  I  would be glad  to know how do I tell back program instance 1 about the value `hhh` when second instance of program is run

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to a **massive** topic called [Inter-process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). There are a number of ways to achieve this, and it somewhat depends on your platform. All conventional mechanisms are available in Python.

I suggest you read the wikipedia article, formulate a plan, then ask any specific questions that arise.

Comment: Well i know it , but how do i achieve pythonically ? I mean in python ..

Comment: The subprocess module? Writing to files? Sockets?

Comment: @sweeneyrod only socket

Comment: @user2528042 I mean those are ways you could communicate between processes.

Comment: @sweeneyrod which ways ?

Comment: @user2528042 "The subprocess module? Writing to files? Sockets?" <- these ways...

Comment: @sweeneyrod Ok how do i achieve through sockets here ?

Comment: @user2528042 That is a broad question. Why not try, and come back if you have a specific problem?

Comment: Ok  @sweeneyrod atleast if you have any reference for this thing in sockets ! well I know socket programming